# What is the point of quoting the argument of the macro?

Tags: macros, m4

Reading the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/html_node/Input-processing.html) of the m4 macro language I have found that example:

```
changequote([,])dnl
define([gl_STRING_MODULE_INDICATOR],
  [dnl comment
  GNULIB_[]translit([[$1]], [a-z], [A-Z])=1dnl
])dnl
  gl_STRING_MODULE_INDICATOR([strcase])
```

which produces:

```
  GNULIB_STRCASE=1
```

But if one omits to quote `strcase` we have the same result:

```
  gl_STRING_MODULE_INDICATOR(strcase)
```

produces

```
  GNULIB_STRCASE=1
```

Why quoting `strcase`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes are required in case `strcase` is defined as a macro. For example, if we have `define(strcase, foo)`, then `gl_STRING_MODULE_INDICATOR(strcase)` will expand first into `gl_STRING_MODULE_INDICATOR(foo)` and then into `GNULIB_FOO=1`.

In general, well-written m4 input will continue to function when certain words unexpectedly happen to be defined as macros.